# Install Canon LiDE 300 / 400 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, scanner, canon, sane

Unable to install Canon LiDE 300 on Ubuntu 18.04. How to solve it?

Comment: Hello and welocome to AU.  Please review this [link](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly to improve your chances of getting a correct and accurate answer.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the [linux drivers from canon?](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/scanners/photo-scanner/canoscan-lide-300?tab=drivers_downloads)

Comment: Another link: https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/scanners/lide_series/canoscan-lide-300.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)

Comment: Comment: I have a LiDE 110, and came to this thread when trying to configure it on my ubuntu 18. In my case, xsane was already installed, just ran it and bam, everything worked smoothly... in case someone also has a 110, this Q&A helped me out as well :)

Answer (score 20):

For Ubuntu **20.04**, this scanner does not work straight forward.
The `ippusbxd` driver tries to get the USB device, and it locks it.
In `dmesg -w` there is a line:

```
usb 1-11: usbfs: process 5756 (ippusbxd) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

To resolve the problem:

```
sudo apt remove ippusbxd
```

and replug the scanner ! (tested on live USB unmodified Focal).

Comment: This absolutely worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: What you describe is what I experienced, but I couldn't fix it by just removing `ippusbxd`, I had to also add `saned` to `lp` group by doing `sudo adduser saned lp`.

I figured this since the device was under the `lp` group in `/dev/bus/usb...`

Thanks!

Comment: Just noting I did NOT need to add saned to the lp group. YMMV?

Comment: I can say that this also works with LiDE 400 on Ubuntu 20.04.  Moreover, I no longer need to use the precarious scangearmp2 software that Canon provides as the scanning software.

Comment: I had the same issue with a Lexmark printer on Ubuntu 20.04 and solved it by removing `ippusbxd`. Super!

Comment: My hero! `sudo apt remove ippusbxd` worked for me with Canon LiDE 400 on Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Also restart simple scan if it was opened :)

Answer (score 16):

Download the scanner's linux [driver](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/product_ranges/scanners/) from the Canon website. It's the same driver for related models: `scangearmp2-3.70-1-deb`

Unpack and install the driver from the download directory:

```
./install.sh
```

Canon's own driver is not enough though, to get the Canon scanner working. It only half works. Assuming you have installed Sane. Sane will recognise the scanner.

```
$ sane-find-scanner

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1912 [LiDE 400]) at libusb:003:008
```

But it won't work.

```
$ scanimage -L

No scanners were identified

$ scanimage --format=png > test.png

scanimage: no SANE devices found
```

Likewise, SimpleScan won't yet detect the scanner.

It will scan at this stage by running Canon's own scanning software, supplied with the scanner download: scangearmp2. But this software is as rudimentary as toddler's tea set. It won't even let you change the resolution, filetype or scan area.

But thanks to the good work being done by [@pekhterev](https://gitlab.com/pekhterev) and [Rolf Bensch](https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/commits/master), the scanner will run if you install some more home-grown software.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sane-project/sane-git
sudo apt-get update
```

(source [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Erolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git))

```
sudo apt install libsane-common
sudo apt install sane-utils
sudo apt install xsane
```

([source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends))

The scanner worked from Xsane, after doing this. And from Gimp, by calling Xsane (it sees it as a pixma:04A91912 scanner). But the image was dull.

Thankfully, it now also works from SimpleScan.

---

By the way, when I contacted Canon for help because their scanner wasn't working, they told me that they "don't support Linux". I replied by pointing out that they had taken the time to supply a driver, so surely they would want to make sure it actually worked when people installed it. But they simply repeated that they "don't support Linux".

Comment: The ppa address changed to: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sane-project/sane-git` . With this info I got the CanoScan Lide 400 working on Ubuntu 18.04 with sane.

Comment: If you want release instead of nightly snapshots, you can use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sane-project/sane-release`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my amateur advice. After all the above, `xsane` still could not find the USB scanner on my system.

Make sure the scanner is not asleep, plug it out and then in, then run:

```
sudo sane-find-scanner
```

you should see this or something like it:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1913 [LiDE 300]) at libusb:001:009
```

Go to the directory `/etc/sane.d/canon_dr.conf` and put the vendor and product numbers in that file.

At the bottom of the files I added the following lines:

```
# LiDE-300
usb 0x04a9 0x1913
```

I also stuck that in `canon630u.conf` (just to be sure)

After that, `xsane` finds the scanner and I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a USA Linux driver from Canon:
[USA driver link Linux 64 bit](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/scanners/photo-scanner/canoscan-lide-400?tab=drivers_downloads)