# How To Install CanoScan LIDE 400 Scanner On Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon, sane, xsane

Gentlemen,

I am a complete newb after ditching Win 10 for Ubuntu so go easy on me & be clear with your writing points.
I joined this site 5 minutes ago specifically to ask this question.

Yes, I've been to the Canon site and downloaded the driver tarballs which I successfully extracted
.
Now what?

Despite all my best efforts I have no idea how to install the drivers and get the scanner going. I searched all over (including this site), and nobody seems to know a working solution.

Kindly point out in very simple terms how to install and setup the above scanner on the version of Ubuntu given. Imagine I'm totally retarded in your detailed & thorough working "How To" explanation. Much appreciated.

---

Thanks all,

I very much appreciate all the time and effort spent helping me, a complete stranger.

A lot has changed since I first posted. I did get my device working, although I have no idea how. I worked though all your helpful suggestions and something "clicked".

I moved on to try Mint 20 to give that a whirl. I experienced the same problem there that couldn't be fixed by the methods given. Strange, because I thought Mint is based on Ubuntu?

So, I ditched that in favour of Manjaro KDE where similar issues occurred with my Scanner plus all my Audio is screwed up no matter how I changed the settings according to online help posts. Out of frustration I changed yet again to the Manjaro Gnome variant where everything works fine "out-the-box".

I'm still considering building a system where Debian is alongside Arch and instead of "Distro-Hopping", merely change the settings in Arch or Debian with the tools available to make the unique version tailored to specific need.

Thanks again all. This matter can now be considered closed.

Answer (score 6):

Not long ago, I myself bought a Canon scanner Lide 300. The driver installation for Lide 400 include the same steps.
In my first attempt to install the Linux drivers for my Canon scanner, I failed miserably multiple times. But the scanner worked flawlessly with Windows driver. Over the short period of time, trying and failing, I finally found a way to make the scanner work with Linux.
This is my quick guide, how to make the scanner work with Linux system(I tested it on Ubuntu 18.04)! Please, just follow the steps. Should one of the steps not work, try to do the troubleshooting suggestions.
DO NOT continue with the next step, until the previous one is working.

**Step 1 - Scanner recognition**

First, all necessary packages have to be installed:

> `sudo apt update`
>
> `sudo apt install sane-utils libusb-dev usbutils`

In order to recognize the connected devices via USB, you can use the command `lsusb`. The scanner from Canon can be filtered out by running:

> `lsusb | grep '04a9'`

The identifier *04a9* is specific for Canon devices. If no output line is shown after execution of previous command, the device is not recognized.

Troubleshooting suggestions:

1. Check the connection between scanner and computer.
2. Restart the system, but be sure, that the scanner is properly connected to the computer.
3. The scanner make some noise adjusting the header during the system start. If that is not the case, try to plug in the scanner in a different USB slot.
4. If you have a Windows system, try to test the USB connection by installing the scanner driver. Canon don't support Linux, but has a good implemented Windows driver.

**Step 2 - Scanner identification**

Now, you can run the command `lsusb` in your terminal and should see the
[output of the lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h066.png). The yellow framed output line shows the scanner connection. By inserting the bus and device number specific to your system, you can make the request about the permission settings for the particular connection. For example, in my case the bus ID is 001 and device ID is 002. The resulting command line is based on informations about my system is:

> `getfacl /dev/bus/usb/001/002`

Remember to use your own connection specifications for the request!!!
The output of the command will show you the group, you have to join as a user. In my case, it is the group *lp*, so I join the *saned* group(scanner management group) and *lp*.

> `sudo usermod -aG saned,lp $USER`
>
> `sane-find-scanner` will recognize the scanner and show the [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8J3j.png).

Troubleshooting suggestions:

1. You can see the groups, you as a user are participating in, if you type in `cat /etc/group | grep $USER`. The groups *saned* and *lp* should be in the list. If not, try to execute the usermod command again.

**Step 3 - Software equipment**

Although the scanner was found, in my case, the identification of scanner by running `scanimage -L` failed. This has to do with the sane software.

The suggestion from markling to use the repository([Install Canon LiDE 300 / 400 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107632/install-canon-lide-300-400-on-ubuntu-18-04)) worked for me. However, the compilation and installation of the latest sane is in my opinion the cleaner solution.

As preparation, you have to install the prerequisites:

> `sudo apt install build-essential libieee1284-3 gphoto2 autoconf automake libtool gettext git autopoint autoconf-archive pkg-config libjpeg-dev`

Now, you can enter the folder of your choice and run:

> `git clone https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends.git`
>
> `cd backends`
>
> `./autogen.sh`
>
> `BACKENDS="canon pixma" ./configure`
>
> `make`
>
> `make install`

After the installation, you should be able to identify your scanner. The output of `scanimage -L` should look like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvWoj.png). If you ran `scanimage -V`, you will get the information about the sane backend version. In my case, by compiling the newest version, the backend status changed from 1.0.27 to 1.0.29.

**Step 4 - Additional Software(optional)**

By the way, the scan utility I like the most is SimpleScan:

> `sudo apt simple-scan`

Comment: Thanks. lsusb listed loads of anonymous hitachi devices and no Canon scanner listed at all.  Attempting install of build-essential returned "command not found" response. Still working through the getfacl stuff before doing usermod. On a bright note I have Simple Scan, it came with my Ubuntu and I intend using that when everything is working. Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me, thanks so much!

Comment: Coming back to this later (2022) it doesn't work - I had errors around usbfs not claiming the device, which I traced to ippusbxd - a new "helpful" handler for printers which ... isn't - it can be removed with     apt purge ippusbxd with no great problem, and then all is good.

Comment: Thank you @MarkWilliams! That helped me with my LiDE 400 scanner!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same scanner and got it working without the drivers from the Canon website or compiling any software myself.

Ubuntu and other Linux distributions use SANE as a back-end to communicate with scanners. Ubuntu 18.04 has an older version of SANE that does not support the CanoScan LiDE 400 yet, but you can use a repository created by Rolf Bensch to easily install the latest release which does support that scanner:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It should update the existing SANE version. After a quick reboot the Simple Scan program that comes with Ubuntu was able to use the scanner. I installed `gscan2pdf` to create PDF documents from the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simpler solution, and, this is exactly how I got my LiDE 400 to work with XSane in Ubuntu 18.04 (I forget if I'm using 18.04.2 or what sub release):

[Rolf Bensch's PPA webpage for SANE](https://launchpad.net/%7Erolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git)

I configured the PPA as per the instructions there, I launched Synaptic and reloaded the package list. I made only these changes:

```
Commit Log for Thu Apr 23 14:18:55 2020 Upgraded the following packages: libsane-common (1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.2) to
1.0.29+git20200422-bionic1

libsane1 (1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.2) to
1.0.29+git20200422-bionic1

python3-update-manager (1:18.04.11.10) to 1:18.04.11.12

sane-utils (1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.2) to
1.0.29+git20200422-bionic1

update-manager (1:18.04.11.10) to 1:18.04.11.12

update-manager-core (1:18.04.11.10) to 1:18.04.11.12

Installed the following packages: libsane (1.0.29+git20200422-bionic1)
```

First time I connected the LiDE 400 USB cable to the system AFTER the update, XSane launches and I make scans. This all took place just a few hours ago, and is my only effort to get it working - first try!

HTH.

Note: I located some Canon Germany software for Linux, no other country I searched had it, it is called Scan Gear, and this software might be necessary for the scanner buttons to cause any activity inside the OS. I didn't install Scan Gear, I don't use such functions.

Updated link, as the original link has been deleted: [https://launchpad.net/~sane-project/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git](https://launchpad.net/%7Esane-project/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git)

Comment: link is broken :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [SANE got updated](http://sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON).  The Canon CanoScan LiDE 400 scanner works out of the box with XSane, up to and including 4800 dpi.  So it works for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

rgagit's answer worked best for me with slight changes made.

**Step 2**

sane-find-scanner always gave me errors on accessing the scanner with something like this

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1912 [LiDE 400]) at libusb:001:003
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x3431 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

To fix this I wrote a little service that will set the correct permissions on startup. First the files

*/etc/systemd/system/set.usb.permissions.service*

```sh
[Unit]
Description=Job that runs your user script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/set_usb_permission
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*/usr/bin/set_usb_permission* (make sure you apply execute permission to this)

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
chmod -R a+w /dev/bus/usb
exit 0
```

After that do

```
$ systemctl reload-daemon
$ systemctl enable set.usb.permissions.service
```

After that the permissions should work

***Step 3***

I found it easier to use the precompiled version from https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/-/releases
I just unzip the contents. Go to the folder and do

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After those steps my Lide 400 finally works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I installed Canon own Ubuntu driver from their pages...yes it works flawlessly. No problems at all. It is relatively easy if you follow the guideline given in a Canon manual. I am using Ubuntu 22.04. See:

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/scanners/photo-scanner/canoscan-lide-400?tab=drivers_downloads

You can also add ICC profile, but I do not know how to do such a thing yet. :-)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1233961)