# Cannon LIDE 300 doesn't work with Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, scanner

I have a CanonScan LIDE 300 and system Kubuntu 20.04 on Aspire 5. I tried different scanning programs -- they see the scanner but "cannot connect" when I try to scan. What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You may need to install proprietary drivers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Canon LiDE 300 / 400 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107632/install-canon-lide-300-400-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: This one worked: https://askubuntu.com/a/1241451/167293 !!